# Tensorflow (or Pytorch?) with a cost function defined in terms of Monte Carlo sampling (cost function that changes every epoch)

Tags: tensorflow, math, physics, pytorch, mathematical-optimization

Edit: I've essentially rewritten this to be (hopefully) much clearer and more concise.  Here's the new version, followed by the original version.

---

I'm currently using TensorFlow for a physics optimization problem (the physics details/background should be mostly irrelevant, though see below if you're interested and understand the jargon).  This actually has nothing to do with machine learning; I'm just using TF for the automatic differentiation.

So, say one is optimizing x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub> with a loss function L(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub>).  The problem I have is that L(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub>) is impossible to calculate exactly and efficiently; however, it can be approximated by sampling.  That is, L(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub>) is nearly equal to some:

l(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub>) = Σ<sub>i</sub> λ<sub>i</sub>(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub>)

where each λ<sub>i</sub> can be efficiently calculated. The catch, though, is the form of each λ<sub>i</sub> depends on the current values of x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub>.  That is, the sampling isn't "random" but is done in a controlled way based on the current value of the parameters.

For the optimization problem, the idea is to use l instead of L as the cost function.  The complication is that l changes every iteration (or "epoch" in ML terminology).  So, the algorithm is:

At each epoch:

1. start with l=0; form of l as a function of the x<sub>k</sub> is unknown at this point
2. determine the form of λ<sub>1</sub>.  Then evaluate λ<sub>1</sub> (and automatically ∂λ<sub>1</sub>/∂x<sub>k</sub>)
3. Do the sum over i, in the process defining and evaluating l (and automatically ∂l/∂x<sub>k</sub>).
4. update x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub> based on the derivatives ∂l<sub>i</sub>/∂x<sub>k</sub>.

I'm not sure how to deal with this in TensorFlow, since "if" statements don't work.  I know there are TensorFlow conditionals (tf.cond) but I've had various problems with that, and I'm not even sure if this is the right place to use tf.cond.  Would PyTorch be any better?

[On the physics background: I'm finding the ground state of a quantum spin system; the loss function is the energy, which I'm calculating with the variational Monte Carlo method.  What I called λ<sub>i</sub> is the local energy of a certain spin configuration.  Then a random spin is flipped, and this new spin configuration is accepted with probability = ratio of the wavefunction amplitudes.  λ<sub>i+1</sub> is the local energy of the new spin configuration, and so on.]

---

Original version:
Basically, the issue is that my loss function is not rigidly defined, but changes every iteration.

How this arises:
Let's say my variables being optimized are x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub> and my loss function is L(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub>).  In the problem I'm working with, to exactly calculate L(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub>) would involve doing an intractably large sum, so the only way is to calculate L(x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub>) by a Monte Carlo sampling method.  Specifically, the method is a Markov chain Monte Carlo (i.e. sequential sampling) method.

In practice, what my situation basically is:

With the sampling method, I have something like L(x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub>) = L<sub>1</sub>(x<sub>i<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub></sub>,...,x<sub>i<sup>1</sup><sub>n</sub></sub>) + L<sub>2</sub>(x<sub>i<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub></sub>,...,x<sub>i<sup>2</sup><sub>n</sub></sub>) + ... + L<sub>M</sub>(x<sub>i<sup>M</sup><sub>1</sub></sub>,...,x<sub>i<sup>M</sup><sub>n</sub></sub>).  The important point is that the functions L<sub>1</sub>, L<sub>2</sub>, ... are not set in stone (both in terms of their functional form, and in terms of which subset of variables they depend on).  To calculate L, one fist starts with an L<sub>1</sub> (essentially, the general form of the L<sub>k</sub> is set, but some free parameters remain.  Typically we start with a "random" L<sub>1</sub>).  Then we generate an L<sub>2</sub> "candidate" by randomly generating the free parameters within it.  This is then accepted or rejected depending on the values of some quantities depending on the x<sub>1</sub>...<sub>N</sub> variables.  Once an L<sub>2</sub> is found, it's evaluated and added to the total L, and we move on to L<sub>3</sub>, and so on.  To calculate L again, the whole process is repeated.

For optimization, this whole process is repeated each iteration (or "epoch" in ML terminology).   Even though the precise functional form of  L varies from epoch to epoch, for any given values of x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub>, the value of L(x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub>) is well defined (to within the accuracy of the approximation), so the optimization should still converge.

The question is: can one do this in TensorFlow?  It's easy to write regular Python code, using if statements, to evaluate L(x<sub>1</sub>, ..., x<sub>N</sub>), but that doesn't translate well to TensorFlow.  Would PyTorch be any better?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, MCMC is available via libraries like [`pyMC3`](https://docs.pymc.io/) and [`tensorflow-probability`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/). Hands-on examples for both frameworks are available in a the great [Probabilistic Programming and Bayesian Methods for Hackers](http://camdavidsonpilon.github.io/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/).

Regarding your actual computation, I am not exactly sure if I follow. Generally, backpropagation through random sampling comes in two main flavors: pathwise derivative and the score function. Both happen to be described concisely in [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html), though you may be able to find a better resource. I don't think your problem lends itself to pathwise-derivative because of the size of the space of paths and I am not sure if score function will work either.

One idea which *may* be applicable, but which  I cannot judge without additional knowledge, is an expectation-maximization approach. Is the following possible for your problem?

1. Take N samples from your Markov chain `[S1, ..., SN]` (expectation)
2. Calculate loss `L(S1) + ... + L(SN)`, do a minimization step on it (minimization)
3. Repeat

Comment: Thanks for your help! 1. I'm aware of libraries like TF probability, but they didn't seem to be of much relevance (what I'm doing is MCMC in name, but the details are very specific and it's actually not hard to code "from scratch") 2. Yes, what you describe is exactly what I want to do, but since L(S1) + ... + L(SN) is different every epoch, one has to define it with "if" statements, which seems to be incompatible with the graph-building of TensorFlow. (Sorry for the unclear original explanation; please see the rewritten version I just posted).

Comment: Ideally you can use tf.where and run everything under a tf.function. Failing this you can just write "regular" python code. TFP has an [example of MCEM](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Linear_Mixed_Effects_Models.ipynb), which is what youre doing.